# Setting order of injection values from properties in Spring Boot for @Value

Tags: spring-boot, properties, annotations, inject

I have a question, about setting order for injection the @Value annotation. I tried with @Order, but for this case, that doesn't work. 
Why do I ask about that? Because some values are dependent on the others. I can make more logic in @PostConstructor, but if exists any solution for control of order it will be helpful for me.

To clarify, an example that not works:

```
@Value("${first}")
@Order(1)
public void setFirst(boolean first) {
    FIRST = first;
}

@Value("${second}")
@Order(2)
public void setSecond(String second) {
    SECOND = second;
    if(first){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use Environment class in order to get a value if something is valid. For example:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;  

@Value("${first}")
public void setFirst(boolean first) {
      FIRST = first;
      if (FIRST) 
         SECOND = env.getProperty("second");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two global variables such as

```
private boolean FIRST;
private String SECOND;
```

Then you can achieve this as follows:

```
@Value("${first}")
public void setFirst(boolean first) {
    FIRST = first;
}

@Value("${second}")
public void setSecond(String second) {
    SECOND = second;
    if(FIRST){
        //do something
    }
}
```